# How to fix " class file for okhttp3.HttpUrl not found"?

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I'm trying to make an http post request to get a token during login, the only error it throws is "error: cannot access HttpUrl class file for okhttp3.HttpUrl not found". I inserted that library even though it's supposedly not required in Retrofit 2 to be inserted.

Comment: Are you trying to use okhttp from Retrofit in your project?

Comment: Yes, error is in .baseUrl("my url") line

Comment: Replace `implementation` with `api` and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry, how to do this?

Comment: In build.gradle file where you added retrofit package, you wrote `implementation`, replace it with `api` then try to use oktthp classes

Comment: `api com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:VERSION`

Comment: Some error again

Comment: Let me ask you the first question again, 
Are you trying to use *okhttp classes*  from Retrofit in your project? Or are you just using retrofit classes?

Comment: And are you using Java 7 or 8?

Comment: @ZohaibAmir okhttp classes from Retrofit I think, Java